# I need to count like characters in the same position in python, but I have no idea how to get it right, as i am new to the program

Tags: python, string, count

Write a Python script that asks the user to enter two DNA 
sequences with the same length. If the two sequences have
different lengths then output "Invalid input, the length must
be the same!" If inputs are valid, then compute how many dna bases at the 
same position are equal in these two sequences and output the
answer "x positions of these two sequences have the same 
character". x is the actual number, depending on the user's
input.

Below is what I have so far.

```
g=input('Enter DNA Sequence: ')
h=input('Enter Second DNA Sequence: ')

i=0
count=0

if len(g)!=len(h):
        print('Invalid')
else:
    while i<=len(g):
        if g[i]==h[i]:
            count+=1
        i+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: So, what's the actual problem you have?

Comment: whoops. it gives me this when i run the program:

Comment: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: i<=len(g) - the index is from 0 to len(g) - 1, so here is your error...

Comment: this works well too. i'm new to programming and whatnot so simple stuff still gets me

Comment: You don't need to initiallize `i`

Answer (score 5):

Do this in your while loop instead (choose better variable names in your actual code):

```
for i, j in zip(g, h):
    if i == j:
        count += 1
```

OR replace the loop entirely with

```
count = sum(1 for i, j in zip(g, h) if i == j)
```

This will fix your index error.  In general, you shouldn't be indexing lists in python, but looping over them.  If you *really* want to index them, the `i <= len(g)` was the problem... it should be changed to `i < len(g)`.

---

If you wanted to be really tricky, you could use the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0`:

```
count = sum(int(i == j) for i, j in zip(g, h))
```

Comment: or just `sum(i == j for i, j in zip(g, h))`

Comment: @gnibbler or even `sum(map(str.__eq__, g, h))` - and if that throws a `TypeError` then the strings aren't equal lengths

Comment: @gnibbler I thought about writing it like that, but it doesn't make it as clear as to what is going on, and since this is clearly a new user I didn't want to blow their mind too much :)

Comment: @user2856713 If you use the one-liner method (called a *list comprehension*) then you don't need to initiallize `count` to zero (or anything for that matter) before that line.

Comment: @SethMMorton, list comprehension uses `[]`. What you have here is called a generator expression

Comment: @gnibbler Yup, you're right.  I shouldn't answer questions while watching TV.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is your loop condition. Your code gives you an `IndexError`; this means that you tried to access a character of a string, but there is no character at that index. What it means here is that `i` is greater than the `len(g) - 1`.

Consider this code:

```
while i<=len(g):
    print(i)
    i+=1
```

For `g = "abc"`, it prints

```
0
1
2
3
```

Those are four numbers, not three! Since you start from `0`, you must omit the last number, `3`. You can adjust your condition as such:

```
while i < len(g):
    # do things
```

---

But in Python, you should avoid using `while` loops when a `for`-loop will do. Here, you can use a for-loop to iterate through a sequence, and `zip` to combine two sequences into one.

```
for i, j in zip(g, h):
    # i is the character of g, and j is the character of h
    if i != j:
        count += 1
```

You'll notice that you avoid the possibility of index errors and don't have to type so many `[i]`s.

Answer (score 0):

`i<=len(g)` - replace this with `i<len(g)`, because index counting starts from 0, not 1. This is the error you are facing. But in addition, your code is not very pretty...

First way to simplify it, keeping your structure:

```
for i in range(len(g)):
    if g[i]==h[i]:
            count+=1
```

Even better, you can actually make it a one-liner:

```
sum(g[i]==h[i] for i in range(len(g)))
```

Here the fact that `True` is evaluated to 1 in Python is used.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Your solution already does it though, so I've +1'ed it rather than editing my answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
g = raw_input('Enter DNA Sequence: ')
h = raw_input('Enter Second DNA Sequence: ')
c = 0
count = 0

if len(g) != len(h):
    print('Invalid')
else:
    for i in g:
        if g[c] != h[c]:
            print "string does not match at : " + str(c)
            count = count + 1
        c = c + 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if(len(g)==len(h)):
   print sum([1 for a,b in zip(g,h) if a==b])
```

Edit: Fixed the unclosed parens.  Thanks for the comments, will definitely look at the generator solution and learn a bit - thanks!

Comment: This is not a readable solution and therefore I conclude it is not a good solution. It's not even efficient — you construct a list when a generator expression would do. It also doesn't explain what was wrong with the above code, and doesn't fix what was wrong but rather throws it out in favor of this solution.

Comment: Plus, there is an unclosed parenthesis